# Django Error local variable 'Person' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

I'm trying to make an app where pet's owners can create their own profile and upload pictures of their pets.

When a user create an account or login , he get redirected into profile  . The profile page should display his info e.g name instead I receive this error.

```
UnboundLocalError at /profile/
local variable 'Person' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET 
Request URL: /profile/ 
Django Version: 1.4.3 
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError 
Exception Value: local variable 'Person' referenced before assignment 


Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\o\mysite\pet\views.py in Profile 

60.  return render_to_response('profile.html', {'Person': Person}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The problem is linking to my Profile function at views.py

My parts of my views.py

```
@login_required     
def Profile(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        Person = request.user.get_profile
        return render_to_response('profile.html', {'Person': Person}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My profile.html

```
{% if Person %}
<ul>
        <li>Name : {{Person.user}} </li>
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Pet(models.Model):
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/",blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

Comment: `Person - request.user.get_profile` should be `Person = request.user.get_profile()`

Comment: Yeah , I still get the error

Comment: It;s the arrangement of your code

Comment: The `def Profile(request):` in your `models.py` is also not correct. That seems to me like it should live in `urls.py`.

Comment: @limelights thank for the help , I must of copied it into the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put Person at the top of request.user.is_authenticated. And you forgot to put '()' in get_profile

```
@login_required     
def Profile(request):
    Person = request.user.get_profile()
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
    return render_to_response('profile.html', {
        'Person': Person
     }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Your spot on! Thank you :]

Comment: , what does local variable 'Person' referenced before assignment mean?

Comment: You render a null Person variable. If you render a variable, you must check it if you call it correctly and you define it.

Comment: And I think you render null Person because you forgot to put '()' in get_profile which result to no data

Comment: Thank you cathy, your a hero :]

Comment: Slowly you be learning it and someday it will be easy for you to debug :)